# Tensorflow loss value is Nan with sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a 11 layer fully convolutional network. The input is an image 480x640x1 and the output labels is also an image 480x640x1. For training I am using sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(). But the loss value I am gettins is NaN. I have attached a snippet of my code for reference.

```
 x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,480,640,1))
 y=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,(None,480,640,1))
 logits=Model1(x)
 loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=tf.squeeze(y,squeeze_dims=[3]))) 
 optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)
 Trainables=optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

So the Model1 returns a tensor of shape(6,480,640,1) (batch size is 6) and the y placeholder is (6,480,640,1). How do I solve the NaN value the loss tensor gets?

Answer (score 0):

Some initial thoughts about why you are getting NaN:

1. Check your learning rate, try reduce it to some smaller value such as `1e-5` and see how it goes. It might because you are having a relatively large learning rate.
2. Clip the gradients by [tf.clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value) to prevent too aggressive updates.
3. What is the activation function you are using? If you have 11 layers, you may want to have tf.nn.relu as your activation function.
4. There might be something wrong with your computation graph, you can test this by adding [tf.check_numerics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/check_numerics) to each layer and see if the NaNs come from a specific layer.